# how to decrease the distance between the root concept and the level 1 concept in mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to decrease the distance between the root concept and the level 1 concept. What can I do? thanks.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}%,backgrounds
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{root concept}+=[concept color=blue!20,minimum size=2cm,font=\sffamily\huge]
\tikzstyle{level 1 concept}+=[sibling angle=60,font=\sffamily\large]
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
\node [concept] (n1) {scale}
    child[concept color=red,grow=30] {node[concept] (c1) {bad}}
    child[concept color=orange,grow=90] {node[concept] (c2) {worse}}
    child[concept color=green,grow=150] {node[concept] (c3) {worst}}
    child[concept color=lime,grow=210] {node[concept] (c4) {good}}
    child[concept color=blue!50,grow=-30] {node[concept] (c5) {better}}
    child[concept color=pink,grow=-90] {node[concept] (c6) {best}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

when I set the level distance = 3.5cm

[image]

Comment: `level distance`.

Comment: @symbol1 thanks for your answer, but I can not find a suitable distance through setting the distance, what else can I set at the same time.

Comment: I guess no. You can find the structure of the connecting bar [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288682/51022), which shows its rigidity.

Comment: Well I was not tell the full story. You still have `segment angle` but that does not help. (It helps if you want ≥20. But apparently you want ≤20.)

Comment: Why hasn't anyone posted a MWE?